# Make a multisampling fbo without GLkit

Tags: swift, opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So i am trying to make a cross platform program so I am avoiding using too many glkit specific functions.

Anyway right now I have been drawing primitive shapes (dots and triangles) into a fbo's texture.  However I now need to multi-sample what goes on the screen that way the edges of the shapes look better.  So my goal would be to make another FBO (FBO 2) that would anti-aliased a texture from another FBO (FBO 1) and display this beautiful anti-aliased texture to the screen.

Unfortunately any and all resources I can find about this use Apple's specific methods for doing so. Furthermore I haven't gotten it to work anyways.  Here is my code I use for making and activating frame buffers.

```
import Foundation
import GLKit
import OpenGLES

class RenderTexture2 {
    var framebuffer:GLuint = 0
    var tex:GLuint = 0
    var old_fbo:GLint = 0



    init(widthi: GLsizei, heighti: GLsizei)
    {

    }

    func begin()
    {
        glGetIntegerv(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING), &old_fbo)
        glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), framebuffer)
    }

    func checkStatus()
    {
        let status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER))
        if (status != GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE))
        {
            print("DIDNT GO WELL WITH")
            print(status)
        }
    }

    func end()
    {
        glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(old_fbo))
    }

    func loadTexture(name: String, type: String) -> GLuint
    {

        var it:GLKTextureInfo = GLKTextureInfo()


        let pic = UIImage(named: name + "." + type)!.CGImage
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: type)

        do
        {
            //try it = GLKTextureLoader.textureWithContentsOfFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: type)!, options: nil)
            try it = GLKTextureLoader.textureWithContentsOfFile(path!, options: nil)
        }
        catch
        {
            do
            {
                //print("ERR Loading: " + path!)
                try it = GLKTextureLoader.textureWithCGImage(pic!, options: nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error loading UIImage: " +  pic.debugDescription)
                it = GLKTextureInfo()

            }

        }

        return it.name

    }

    func load(width: GLsizei, height: GLsizei)
    {
        glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0)


        glGetIntegerv(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING), &old_fbo)

        glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer)
        tex = loadTexture("AF", type: "png")

        glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), framebuffer)


        //glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_NEAREST)
        //glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_NEAREST)


        glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), tex)
        glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0, GL_RGBA, GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), 0, GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), nil)
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), tex, 0)

        glClearColor(0, 0.0, 0, 0.0)
        glClear(GLenum(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))

        let status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER))
        if (status != GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE))
        {
            print("DIDNT GO WELL WITH", width, " " , height)
            print(status)
        }

        glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(old_fbo))

    }

}
```

This code works right now as your basic cut and dry fbo.

What do I need to change to make this work?  perhaps if I changed some of the texture filtering/mapping parameters?

Thanks much!